# Swing : change selected tab value

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I want to change the value of the selected tab but I don't know how!

```
private JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();
```

I used that to make the second tab active but it doesn't work : `tab.getSelectedIndex()= 2`

How to change selected tab value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be:

```
tab.setSelectedIndex(2);
```

All available methods can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html).